# CSS Image pos middle in dynamic proportionally height/width div

Tags: html, css

Need to solve this little task:

1. Center vertically and horizontally IMAGE in DIV.
2. DIV height must be proportional to width.
3. DIV width is stretchable (for example 50% of parent div).
4. IMAGE width and height = auto (it must fill div if its width or height > than div width or height, and have primary size if its < div size, and stay proportional).

I know how to make 2 and 3.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="img.png"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

But how to center and middle IMAGE in this DIV? 
There is a lot of ways to make 1 task with non proportional and non strechable div.
But I dont know how to make it all in full house of tasks.

Can you help? HTML and CSS may be any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/42trk8ux/17/

HTML:

```
<div class="width-50">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="aspect"></div>
        <div class="block">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-cell">
                    <img src="img.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.width-50{
    width:50%
}

.parent{
    position: relative;
}

.aspect
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
}

.tbl{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.tbl-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background: #aaa;
}

.tbl-cell img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
    .container img {
        vertical-align : middle
    }
```

? It will verticaly align your image.

Comment: Wrong answer. This situation is a little harder than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
            .container
            {
                    width   :100%;
                    height  :100%;
                    display :table;
            }
            .child
            {
                    vertical-align :middle;
                    display        :table-cell;
            }
            .child img
            {
                    display :block;
                    width   :50%;
                    margin  :0 auto;
            }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
            <div class="child">
                    <img src="img.png"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: .container width 100% and height 100% will not give proportional square div with aspect ratio 1:1

Comment: It must be streched (like in my example).

Comment: Your question is not clear..You are asking to make image vertically and horizontally middle and you want it to be stretched...how is that possible ?

Comment: May be that is possible. I dont know. If its possible to make div like a streched square, then why its not possible center image in that div?

Comment: How a stretched image can be vertically and horizontally middled ?
To make it streched give image css as width:100% and height:100% and display:block...Try this out....

Comment: How? Check this http://jsfiddle.net/42trk8ux/3/. Made it in 2 minutes. The problem that i cant make div cell with aspect ratio 1:1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77846/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-denismart).